# How can I split a two-character string and assign it to separate variables?

Tags: php, arrays, json, split

I want to split two characters from an array element using a substring.

For example, the data from array element `rank_tier` is `52`.

I want to assign `5` to `$firstnumber` and `2` to `$secondnumber`.

My error code is

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

My PHP code

```
<?php
    $url = '#';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $ranktier = json_decode($content, true);

    echo $ranktier['rank_tier'];

    $firstnum = substr($ranktier, 1);
    echo $firstnum;

    $secendnum = substr($ranktier, 1);
    echo $secendnum;
?>
```

Comment: `Message: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: why would you want to use `substr` for an array? where its suffix `str` clearly states it should be used for *strings*.

Comment: `52` is an array? That sounds like a string. If it is an array access it at its index.

Comment: its obvious $ranktier is an array substr expects a string so the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ranktier` is an array.

Assuming `$ranktier['rank_tier']` is a string `52`, you can just access the two characters by their "offset".

```
$firstnum = $ranktier['rank_tier'][0];  // 5
$secendnum = $ranktier['rank_tier'][1];  // 2
```

No functions are required for this task.

If the `52` is not yet a string, cast it as one.

```
$num = (string)$ranktier['rank_tier'];  integer 52 becomes "52"
$firstnum = $num[0];  // 5
$secendnum = $num[1];  // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($ranktier['rank_tier'], 0, 1);
```

Your string is $ranktier['rankt_tier'], so you should put string in substr().

Answer (score 0):

You missed one variable here.
Instead of

```
echo $ranktier['rank_tier'];
```

This should be

```
$ranktier = $ranktier['rank_tier'];

$firstnum = substr($ranktier_num,0,1));
$secendnum = substr($ranktier_num,1,1));
```